# Cannot get right value when use external scope function in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs 1.4.9 and ui-grid 3.1.1

I have used external scope (grid.appScope) to access a function to get value from a cell in grid but I can not get the right value.

The plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/f0c24q5w9Fbx9ap1XUG7?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0c24q5w9Fbx9ap1XUG7?p=preview)

If we click on image of Product 01 to Product 05 we can get the right value, the image will display normally, but if we click on image of Product 20 - Product 23 we can not see the right image.

If we click on one cell (use the `cellNav` feature) and click on the button "Get current focus cell" we always get the right value.

So how can I get the true value through `grid.appScope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the items beneath the visible table have a VERY hard time keeping up. Try this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Grk0vxxmeQpSsLcOW9e?p=preview)

The code that changed:

```
var imageTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="!!row.entity.image" style="text-align: center">'
  + '<img ng-src={{row.entity.image}} width="50px" height="50px" ng-click="grid.appScope.addImage(row.entity.image)"/></div>';
```

[note I removed the quotes]

Comment: Thank you. I'm so surprised when it cause by the quote =.='